# How can I do find and replace parenthesis surrounded text with regex on Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have a document that has (TL by user) all over the place. I'd like to replace this with nothing (thereby deleting it everywhere) but the user could be different or there could be many users (TL by user1) (TL by user3, superuser1). So far I have tried find (TL by .*) and replace with nothing but that gets rid of everything but the user and the surrounding paranthesis for some reason so I'm left with (user1) or (user3,superuser1). How can I get the regex to match and replace the entire match (TL by user) including the parans and everything inside?

This is on Word 2010, I will put more information when I get home later today

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no actual "RegEx" searching in Office, but you can use the "Use Wildcards" option.

So since it's not real RegEx, the `.` doesn't do anything to help. You just need the `*` wildcard.

The next trick is that while performing a wildcard search in Word, the brackets `()` are used for grouping (like in RegEx), so if you want to search for literal brackets you need to escape them with a backslash (`\`).

Putting all that together and I end up with this Find command, which works as you want (based on my testing):

`\(TL by *\)`

Find and Replace dialog settings I used:

[image]

Comment: Caveat: Microsoft Word thinks the list separator is part of the culture set in Windows, so if you use repetition count you need to change accordingly. Example: `{1,5}` is for enUS, `{1;5}` is for daDK.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing version and platform information but I did find [this article](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) on the MS web site. In short,

1. Type in a list of names like below

   ```
   Chuck Norris
   Bruce Lee
   James Bond Bond
   ```
2. On the Home tab, in the **Editing** group, click **Replace** to open the **Find and Replace** dialog box.
3. If you don't see the **Use wildcards** check box, click **More**, and then select the check box. If you don't select the check box, Word treats the wildcard characters as text.
4. Type the following characters in the **Find what** box. Make sure you include the space between the two sets of parentheses:

   > `(<*>) (<*>)`
5. In the **Replace with** box, type the following characters. Make sure you include the space between the comma and the second slash:

   > `\2, \1`
6. Select the table, and then click Replace All. Word transposes the names and separates them with a comma, like so

   ```
   Norris, Chuck
   Lee, Bruce
   Bond, James Bond
   ```

**CAVEAT**, this did not work for me using Office 2011 on OSX 10.10.2. However, there is more information on the page for more advanced features.

Answer (score -1):

See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7 for detail

Microsoft claims its own wildcard language "regular expression" and is available only in Advanced Find or Replace dialogue. And its language is slightly different from other regular expressions.