# Remove of everything between [ and ] in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I need a pattern / search string to remove everything between the "[" and "]" characters. An example would be:

```
This study  [ref] is  a good example
```

This should become:

```
This study  is  a good example
```

I found this regex [here](https://superuser.com/questions/875373/remove-of-everything-between-two-characters-in-word-regex)  `\<(*{1,})\>` but although it works with `<` and `>`, it doesn't with `[` and `]`.

When I use `\[(*{1,})\]`  world "says" that they can't find what I am looking for.

I am trying to remove some formatings from wikipedia articles and this regex doesn't remove the [edit] next to the headings. (I use the merge formating paste)

Comment: Technically it's not regex if it's ms word. as this link mentions.  http://superuser.com/questions/890288/how-can-i-do-find-and-replace-with-regex-on-microsoft-word    And also, If you are editing a wiki page you lose nothing(no formatting), by cut and pasting it into a program that supports regex, then using a regex

Comment: Sorry for using regex, I meant wildcard. I am using Word, because I need to keep the heading style (and the automating numbering with it) that Word proposes. Notepad++ doesn't do that

Comment: The `\ ` escapes special characters such as `[` and `]`. Therefore, if you checked "use wildcards" in the Find & Replace dialog, you need to escape them as `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include my regex : `\[(*{1,})\]`.Somehow, this doesn't match the `[edit]` next to the heading of a wikipedia article

Comment: @Arone did you try clicking the cursor at the beginning of the document before you clicked find?

Comment: According to https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Use-wildcard-characters-to-find-or-replace-text-610e37dc-bb2f-4a8b-8fa5-aa991160eafb, `*` represents already an arbitrary number of string characters. Therefore, you can drop `{1,}`. Alternatively, you could write `\[[a-zA-Z ]{1,}\]`. The `(` and `)` are also not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This two expressions work

```
\[*\]
\[[a-zA-Z ]{1,}\]
```

Further comments:

- `*` represents an arbitrary number of string characters. `{1,}` can only be attached to a single character wildcard. That is the problem with the expression `\[*{1,}\]`.
- The `(` and `)` are not necessary.

See 
https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Use-wildcard-characters-to-find-or-replace-text-610e37dc-bb2f-4a8b-8fa5-aa991160eafb for details on the wildcards.